# How to show only child of current li and hide other li child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have more than one nested ul in my page. Nested ul is displayed via following jquery code.

**Jquery**

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").show("slow");
});
```

But I want to show only one nested ul at one time. I mean when I click one li, it should display its child ul only and hide others child ul. I added following line in my previous jquery code

```
$("li ul").not(this).hide("slow");
```

but it doesn't work.

**CSS**

```
li ul{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Insert + </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="services.php">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="notice.php">Notice and Information</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">View + </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="services.php">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="notice.php">Status</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**try this code**

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").not(this).children("ul").hide("slow");
    $(this).children("ul").show("slow");
});
```

```js
$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").not(this).children("ul").hide("slow");
    $(this).children("ul").show("slow");
});
```

```css
li ul{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="#">Insert + </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="services.php">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="notice.php">Notice and Information</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">View + </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="services.php">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="notice.php">Status</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amal very much

Comment: Glad to help you:)